# Finding Surface Area and Volume of a Rectangular Prism

Tags: area, volume

So this is my work so far:

Rectangle 1: Length: 10 cm; Height: 7 cm

Rectangle 2 and 3: Length: 6 cm; Height: 8 cm

I am getting confused on the question is that the rectangles have different side lengths and the formula is base times width times height. What I'm confused on is what would the base be? I thought it was ten but I am having trouble understanding what the base is. I have mastered this but I am still confused on what I would be. Cause when we had done surface area it wasn't with 3D shapes.

[Surface Area and Volume Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJxbA.png)

Comment: Looks like a triangular prism to me.

Comment: One question at a time, first the surface area. The total surface area comes from 3 rectangles (the side faces) and 2 triangles. You are right that one rectangular area is $10\times 7 \text{ cm}^2$, where $10\text{ cm}$ is one edge of the triangle and $7\text{ cm}$ is the height of the prism. The other two rectangular faces are similar, that each shares an edge with the triangle, and each has the height of the prism as another edge.